# Unauthorized withdrawal of money from my savings account by Bank

Tags: india, banking, fraud, law, bank-statements

I have a Savings Account in a Bank. The bank *withdrew* money (₹ 1,75,000/-) from my savings account by account *without any authorization (no check, no withdrawal slip, or anything of the kind)*. My bank statement do not show any proper details of the transaction.

Here is what my **[image: Bank Statement]** looks like:

As mentioned in the above table, the description has only gibberish with **no Transaction Id created** *or* any other details. I have tried to clarify the details with the bank branch (sent emails, and post mails) for the **past 5 months** with no clear response on their part.

What action should be taken? I am lost.

Comment: You say you have some form of response. Could you include what they've said? There is a difference between "no clear response", and "no details of transaction". In the meantime, I suggest you change your passwords on your bank account, request a new debit card if applicable, etc., as there is a chance your details have been stolen and this is the result of fraud / scam.

Comment: Have you actually called and talked to a real person? It sometimes takes an actual human to fix stuff like this.

Comment: @nosjack or even better - walk into a local branch.